# C# How to include DLL dependencies in build?

Tags: c#, visual-c++, dll

I have a visual c++ project (that builds to a DLL called X) that references another DLL (called Y).

In my visual C++ project for X, I set a reference to Y via project settings, linker, input, and additional dependencies.

Now I have another project, a C# project, Z, which references X.  I include X in Z by adding X as a project dependency.

For some reason X needs to be compiled before I can compile Z (the project won't build everything at the same time).

But then when I run Z, and I hit the reference to Z, I get an exception "Could not load file or assembly 'X' or one of its dependencies".

When I look at Z's build folder, I see X.dll in there, but not Y.dll.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you try adding Y as a dependency to Z?  By the way, if you ever explain this to someone again, consider having one set of names for C++ projects and another set for C# projects (it's a bit hard to follow as you describe it).

Comment: When I'm in Z, the C# project, and I try to add a reference to Y, I get "could not be added, please make sure that the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.  Note:  The project works if I just copy paste Y to my C# project's bin folder.

Comment: Any warnings when rebuilding the solution?

Comment: Nope.  Nothing.  Nothing at all.

Comment: The C# build system is pretty good at knowing when to copy dependent DLLs.  But is powerless when the Y dependency is an unmanaged DLL, there is no metadata that says that X requires it.  Such are the tribulations of native code.  You have to help getting it in the right place.  XCopy in a post build event is one, adding Y to the C# project is one, having Y stored in a directory that is on the PATH is one, pinvoking SetDllDirectory is one, having everything built to the same directory might be one.  Pick whatever is closest to how you intend to deploy your project.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you'll need to edit the project file manually to achieve this behavior. (Unfortunately there are no menu's inside visual C++ projects to do this.)

I would recommend to make a backup before you start editing the project file.

In visual studio you'll need to unload the project file of X (right-click and choose 'unload project' in solution explorer).

Then right-click again and choose 'Edit X.vcxproj'.

Inside the **Project** element you will need to add an ItemGroup like this:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">
  <Content Include="E:\full_path\Y.dll">
    <Link>Y.dll</Link>
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'">
  <Content Include="E:\full_path\Yd.dll">
    <Link>Yd.dll</Link>
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

When you don't have a different debug dll file (or 64 and 32 bit versions), you can use only one Itemgroup and remove the condition attribute. Then it will copy Y.dll to all the project outputs.

Then Save your edits and reload the project (also right-click).

This solves the problem because now, project 'Z' wil know that when it builds project 'X', it will need to **copy Y.dll to** the output of project 'X', or **the parent project Referencing 'X'**.

(It would be better to use a variable instead of a hard coded path, but I wanted to keep the sample simple.)

I use this in many managed C++ projects that reference third party, or open source libraries. And it took me a while to figure this out.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Is this what nuget packages are for?  They put the right DLLs in the right places and add the relevant lines to the project properties file?

Comment: A NuGet package will handle this for you if it is available. It's also possible to create a property sheet, and add this to the project. The contents of the property sheet are imported in the project file when you add it in Visual Studio.